# Resizing iframe, not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, iframe, autoresize

I'm trying to resize an iframe. My code is working in Chrome and Interner Explorer, but not in Firefox. Can someone explain why.

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

function autoResize(id){
var newheight;


if(document.getElementById){
    newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentDocument .body.scrollHeight;

}

document.getElementById(id).height= newheight;

}
</script>
```

And here is my iframe:

```
<iframe id="myframe" src="http://www.somesite.com/content/index.php" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="900px" onLoad="autoResize('myframe');"></iframe>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error here ? Give an alert here and see if you are actually getting the height in firefox ..

Comment: Is www.somesite.com same-origin with your script?  Is the web page in the subframe in quirks mode or standards mode?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you are not sending passing the id as parameter in function call in if statement. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

    function autoResize(id){

    if(document.getElementById(id)){
        document.getElementById(id).height = document.getElementById(id).contentDocument .body.scrollHeight;

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This also works with Chrome and IE, but not with Firefox (18.0.2).